# convert zip byte[] to unzip byte[]

Tags: java

I have `byte[]` of zip file. I have to unzip it without creating new file, and get `byte[]` of that unzip file.
Please help me to do that

Comment: What have you tried so far? ByteArrayInputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream will be useful here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `ZipInputStream` and `ZipOutputStream` (in the package `java.util.zip`) to read and write from ZIP files.

If you have the data in a byte array, you can let these read from a `ByteArrayInputStream` or write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` pointing to your input and output byte arrays.

Answer (score 7):

```java
public static List<ZipEntry> extractZipEntries(byte[] content) throws IOException {
    List<ZipEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
   
    ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println( "entry: " + entry );
        ZipOutputStream stream= new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("F:\\ssd\\wer\\"+entry.getName())));
        stream.putNextEntry(entry);
    }
    zipStream.close();
   
    return entries;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to `deflate` your zipped data and you are too lazy to deal with the streams, you can use the following code:

```
public byte[] deflate(byte[] data) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    inflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!inflater.finished()) {
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one file in the zip, you could use the following code. If there are multiple files, just modify the `if` into a `while`.

```
public static byte[] toUnzippedByteArray(byte[] zippedBytes) throws IOException {
    var zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zippedBytes));
    var buff = new byte[1024];
    if (zipInputStream.getNextEntry() != null) {
        var outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int l;
        while ((l = zipInputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, l);
        }
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
    return new byte[0];
}
```