# Convert Zip byte[] to Unzip byte[] using java code

Tags: java

Could some one help me with the code snippet in converting zip byte[] to unzip byte[] in memory with out writing to a file intermediary

I looked in to this stack overflow "[convert zip byte[] to unzip byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209450/convert-zip-byte-to-unzip-byte)' but not able to get it using java code

Thanks
Somu

Comment: try this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the tools you need for that:

1. [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) - allows you to wrap an array of bytes as a stream.
2. [ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) - reads the zipped stream of bytes and presents them as unzipped ones.
3. [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) - a stream that writes into internal byte buffer.
4. (If using Java 9) [InputStream#transferTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-) - copy from input stream to output stream. (If not using Java 9) [Copy it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574837/connecting-an-input-stream-to-an-outputstream)
5. [ByteArrayOutputStream#toByteArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray()) - extract buffer from the output stream.

Wire them all together and you are done.

Comment: Thank you bezmax, I tried but no luck

Comment: ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(c) //here c containz zipped byte array
                    ZipInputStream zipInputStreamn = new ZipInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    ByteStreams.copy(zipInputStreamn,byteArrayOutputStream)
                    byte[] unZipFileByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
                    println unZipFileByteArray.toString() //this is giving empty array