# Convert zipped []byte to unzip []byte golang code

Tags: go, zip, slice, unzip

I have []byte of zip file. I have to unzip it without creating a new file, and get a []byte of that unzipped file. Please help me to do that.

I am making an API call and the response I get is the []byte in zipped format - I am trying to unzip it - and use it's content for creating a new zip file. So unzip - rezip.

Language: Golang

Code I've used:

```
func UnzipBytes(zippedBytes []byte) ([]byte, error) {

    reader := bytes.NewReader(zippedBytes)
    zipReader, err := zlib.NewReader(reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer zipReader.Close()
    p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(zipReader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return p, nil
}
```

I get an error saying "zlib: invalid header"

The code that was initially used to zip the []byte

```
buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(buffer)
zipFile, err := zipWriter.Create(file.name)
_, err = zipFile.Write(file.content)
```

Hex dump of the []byte - the zippedBytes

```
00059350  78 b4 5b 0d 2b 81 c2 87  35 76 1b 11 4a ec 07 d1  |x.[.+...5v..J...|
00059360  76 77 a2 e1 3b d9 12 e2  51 d4 c5 bd 4b 2f 09 da  |vw..;...Q...K/..|
00059370  f7 21 c7 26 73 1f 8e da  f0 ff a3 52 f6 e2 00 e6  |.!.&s......R....|
```

Comment: Check out the `compress/zlib` package. You can create a `Reader`, providing an input that reads from your `[]byte`, and you can read the decompressed data, obtaining it as a `[]byte` e.g. using `io.ReadAll()`.

Comment: (or `archive/zip`, `compress/gzip`, `compress/flate` etc.  depending on what you mean by "zipped []byte")

Comment: I've tried that icza it did not work - and I found the same question in stackoverflow for Java - and I just copied and pasted for GoLang - cause it's something that's required and should be fairly straightforward to do. I'm looking for the actual code not advice. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: The question itself is under-specified, and "please write code for me" is not an acceptable type of question here (though perhaps it was more acceptable in the past with whatever java question you used as a reference)

Comment: JimB - if you can't be helpful than just please don't help - you can waste your time elsewhere. I am a stackoverflow user for a long time - and what I'm asking is completely straight forward. Since the same exact questions exists and is upvoted in another language - > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209450/convert-zip-byte-to-unzip-byte

Comment: If the obvious use of the `zip` package didn't work, it would really help to have a [mre] showing _what_ didn't work. Otherwise we're just calling `zip.NewReader` for you.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example @JimB

Comment: If you get _"zlib: invalid header"_, that means your `[]byte` is not a "simple" zlib block. Try the other packages suggested by @JimB.

Comment: If you don't know what it is, post the `hex.Dump()` output of its first like 100 bytes and we might be able to help you find out what format it is.

Comment: If `zlib` doesn't work for your "zip", you probably either have a complete archive, in which case you can use the example in the [`archive/zip`](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#example-Reader) docs to unpack the files; or you have raw DEFLATE stream, in which case you can use `compress/flate`.

Comment: You used `zip.Writer` to compress the data. You must close it by calling its `Close()` method. And you must use `zip.Reader` to read it, and use `Reader.Open()` with the same name you used when compressed it `file.content`. If you don't know the name when decompressing, you may see all files in the `Reader.Files` header field.

Comment: @icza - I've added a small portion of the hex.Dump() - JimB- I am not sure I understand the raw DEFLATE stream you are referring to. I can't create the method with the examples provided. Thanks for trying to help both of you.

Comment: don't worry about DEFLATE, it's clear now you are not using that.

Comment: I don't have a file - I have just the []byte at the method shown - so what do you mean you must use Reader.Open() - I've got nothing to open - I've got the contents there in the []byte. that's it. I want to unzip/convert just the []bytes as they are

Comment: OK, now the question contains enough info to answer it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used [`zip.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Writer) to compress the data. You must close it by calling its [`Writer.Close()`](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Writer.Close) method. And you must use [`zip.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Reader) to read it, and use [`Reader.Open()`](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Reader.Open) with the same name you used when compressed it (`file.name`).

This is how it could look like:

```
func UnzipBytes(name string, zippedBytes []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    reader := bytes.NewReader(zippedBytes)
    zipReader, err := zip.NewReader(reader, int64(len(zippedBytes)))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    f, err := zipReader.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return p, nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
filename := "test.txt"
filecontent := []byte("line1\nline2")

buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(buffer)
zipFile, err := zipWriter.Create(filename)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if _, err = zipFile.Write(filecontent); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err = zipWriter.Close(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

decoded, err := UnzipBytes(filename, buffer.Bytes())
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Println(string(decoded))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/zpiAHRHg5Oe)):

```
<nil>
line1
line2
```

If you don't know the name when decompressing, you may see all files in the `Reader.Files` header field. You may choose to open the first file:

```
func UnzipBytes(zippedBytes []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    reader := bytes.NewReader(zippedBytes)
    zipReader, err := zip.NewReader(reader, int64(len(zippedBytes)))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if len(zipReader.File) == 0 {
        return nil, nil // No file to open / extract
    }
    f, err := zipReader.File[0].Open()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return p, nil
}
```

This outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/s0RZEEKVvYf).

Comment: The last function is what I was looking for. I was missing this zipReader.File[0].Open() - Thanks @icza you are a legend! I really appreciate your time. I think this question will also be valuable to others as well - time will tell. Thanks again.